# Match pattern for regex "subtraction" equations

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I want to match a valid "subtraction" equation of an unknown number (non-zero) of 'z' characters.

Valid string examples: "zzz-z=zz" or "zzzz-zzz=z"

Invalid string examples: "z-zz=z" or "zzz-z=z" or "z-zz=-z"

I have tried something like this, but it doesn't work. I believe it has to do with some sort of back-referencing?

```
re.match(r'(z+)\-(z+)\=(?!\2)\1', s)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This in no way invalidates your question or makes it less interesting, but why would you actual use only regex for this?

Answer (score 4):

It's really simple, don't overthink it.

Just break the first `z`s into 2 parts, and match the next two `z`s to the equation:

```
^(z+)(z+)-\1=\2$
```

Check the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/oooOar/1/)

Comment: Omg thanks, I see it now! Didn't think about it this way previously...

Comment: this is brilliant.

Comment: This is very clever. Also a good demo of why regex is not a good tool for this :)

Answer (score 0):

This matches the first two strings ("zzz-z=zz" or "zzzz-zzz=z") without matching the last three ("z-zz=z" or "zzz-z=z" or "z-zz=-z").

```
(z{2,})\-(z{1})\=(z{2})|(z{2,})\-(z{3})\=(z{1})
```

The | is an or operator, so everything before it matches "zzz-z=zz" and everything after it matches "zzzz-zzz=z"

The curly braces are helpful for specifying a range of the number of times you want the character before them to match.

It may need adjusting if there are other valid string examples.